# Input Focus between two React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to achieve the following using React.

- The moment user will start typing in the input box below, a modal
  will appear and user will continue to type there without clicking on
  the Modal's input box
- Once user will click backspace and clear the Modal's input box, it closes the box and focus goes back to the main input empty box.

**Reason on using two Input states:** It will look odd to see the parent input box getting updated behind the Dialog Box.

[image]

Code : https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-reactstrap-forked-r2sns1?file=/src/modal.tsx:0-1658

Parent Component

```
 const App = () => {
  const [openDialog, setDialog] = useState({
    isModalOpen: false,
    value: ""
  });

  const toggle = () => {
    setDialog({ isModalOpen: false, value: "" });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ModalExample
        openDialog={openDialog.isModalOpen}
        query={openDialog.value}
        toggle={() => toggle()}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={openDialog.value}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setDialog({ isModalOpen: true, value: e.target.value })
        }
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Dialog Component

```
const Dialog = ({ openDialog, query, toggle }: any) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState("");
  const [searchResult2, setSearchResult2] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchResult(query);
  }, [query]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current?.focus();
    } else {
      setSearchResult2(searchResult2 + 1);
    }
  }, [searchResult2]);


  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        isOpen={openDialog}
        role="dialog"
        autoFocus={true}
        centered={true}
        size="lg"
        query={query}
        className="exampleModal"
        // @ts-ignore
        tabIndex="-1"
        toggle={toggle}
      >
        <div className="modal-content">
          <ModalHeader
            toggle={toggle}
            className="ett-bg-secondary text-blue m-0"
          >
            <span className="mx-4">Download</span>
          </ModalHeader>
          <div className="px-5 mt-2"></div>
          <Form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              //validation.handleSubmit(e)
              return false;
            }}
          >
            <ModalBody className="">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg">
                  <div className="custom-shadow px-5">
                    <input
                      ref={ref}
                      type="text"
                      value={searchResult}
                      onChange={(e) => setSearchResult(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ModalBody>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

May I know how can I achieve this.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current?.focus();
      if (searchResult?.length < 1) {
        setDialog({ value: "", isModalOpen: false });
      }
    }
  }, [searchResult]);
```

Do not forget to include `setDialog` in the props. Here a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-reactstrap-forked-r8sg8v?file=/src/modal.tsx).

Comment: Accepting this as this solved both of the questions asked. Thank you bro.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this file instead of yours in the sandbox

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState, useRef } 
from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Col,
  Form,
  Modal,
  ModalBody,
  ModalHeader,
  Row
} from "reactstrap";

const Dialog = ({ openDialog, query, toggle }: any) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState("");
  const [searchResult2, setSearchResult2] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchResult(query);
  }, [query]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current?.focus();
    } else {
      setSearchResult2(searchResult2 + 1);
    }
  }, [searchResult2]);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        isOpen={openDialog}
        role="dialog"
        autoFocus={true}
        centered={true}
        size="lg"
        query={query}
        className="exampleModal"
        // @ts-ignore
        tabIndex="-1"
        toggle={toggle}
      >
        <div className="modal-content">
          <ModalHeader
            toggle={toggle}
            className="ett-bg-secondary text-blue m-0"
          >
            <span className="mx-4">Download</span>
          </ModalHeader>
          <div className="px-5 mt-2"></div>
          <Form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              //validation.handleSubmit(e)
              return false;
            }}
          >
            <ModalBody className="">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg">
                  <div className="custom-shadow px-5">
                    <input
                      ref={ref}
                      type="text"
                      value={searchResult}
                      onChange={(e) => setSearchResult(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ModalBody>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
export default Dialog;
```

Comment: What does "dropped it quickly" mean? Please write in complete sentences so you're better understood.

Comment: I added this code to my project and the codesanbox showed me ```Aw, Snap?```

Comment: @BhokluSingh I corrected

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```
const fieldOne = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (fieldOne.current && openDialog && document.activeElement !== fieldOne.current) {
      fieldOne.current.focus();
    }
})
```

And here is demo https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-reactstrap-forked-jomb3d?file=/src/modal.tsx:317-350

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the Modal's *onOpened* Prop:

```
<Modal
  isOpen={openDialog}
  onOpened={onOpened}
  role="dialog"
  autoFocus={true}
  centered={true}
  size="lg"
  query={query}
  className="exampleModal"
  // @ts-ignore
  tabIndex="-1"
  toggle={toggle}
>
```

then focus the reference:

```
const onOpened = () => {
  // consider adding a check that ref.current !== null
  ref.current.focus();
}
```

here's your [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-reactstrap-forked-xpdbrq?file=/src/modal.tsx) edited with those changes, it focuses onOpen. I don't know the second part of your problem is, and what you are trying to to do when you leave the modal. But you could use the Modal's *onClosed* prop and use a callback from the parent.